# Open a URL using check box by embedding a script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I want to make a google script which will open a URL in the same row as the checkbox when it is ticked or marked check. My checkboxes starts in A3:A and it's corresponding links are in C3:C

[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGR4g.jpg)

Project output[image]

[URL opener checkbox](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sa2c3aXJbxa_WwsyRUko3P5ldfzP9SuXboVw0RTdvX0/edit?usp=sharing)

This script opens only the first cell:

```
function processSelectedRows() {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("n- 
   gadget").getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = rows.shift();
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
   if(row[0]) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    setCellColors();
    openURL();
   }
  });
}

function setCellColors() {
  //Get the sheet you want to work with. 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("n-gadget");
  //Grab the entire Range, and grab whatever values you need from it. EX: 
   rangevalues
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
  var rangevalues = range.getValues();
  //Loops through range results
  for (var i in rangevalues) {
   for (var j in rangevalues) {
   //Get the x,y location of the current cell.
    var x = parseInt(j, 10) + 1;
    var y = parseInt(i, 10) + 1;
   //Set the rules logic
    if (rangevalues[i][j] == 1) {
   //Set the cell background
     sheet.getRange(y,x).setBackground("green");
     sheet.getRange(y,x).setFontColor("white");
    }
   }
  }
}


function openURL(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("n-gadget");
 var link = sheet.getRange("C3:C").getValue();
 var title = sheet.getRange("B3:B").getValue();
 showAnchor(title,link);
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
 var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" 
 onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
 var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"check stats");
}
```

Comment: You just added three functions. What's the connection between those functions and the checkbox?

Comment: @TheMaster hi, thanks for the advice. Actually it is a 4-part script. I've updated the code. The first half of the code is the original which highlights in color green when the checkbox is ticked. The second half is an integration which I learned in this platform. It calls a html service which is a popup window. Pls. see the attached images above. The problem is it is only calling the first link. What I want is to call the matching link when the checkbox was marked.

Comment: Is there a trigger attached to a function?

Comment: Actually I've just discovered that the second half of the script triggers regardless of the 1st half was not triggered. As you can see in the attached image I have not marked the checkbox and still the pop-up window executed. But the 1st half is working as is intended, the marked box changed to green background and white text as recently uploaded picture shows.

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured out the solution:

```
var link = sheet.getRange(y,x+2).getValue();
var title = sheet.getRange(y,x+1).getValue();
```

Here's the full code (The data validation is either 1 and 0 instead of TRUE or FALSE):

```
function processSelectedRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("n-gadget");
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    var headers = rows.shift();
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    if(row[0]) {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      setCellColors();
    }
  });
}

function setCellColors() {
  //Get the sheet you want to work with. 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("n-gadget");
  //Grab the entire Range, and grab whatever values you need from it. EX: rangevalues
  //if lower cell is set highlight will move upward
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
 var rangevalues = range.getValues();
  //Loops through range results
 for (var i in rangevalues) {
  for (var j in rangevalues) {
   //Get the x,y location of the current cell. y is row x is column
      var x = parseInt(j, 10) + 1;
      var y = parseInt(i, 10) + 1;
      //var link;
      //var title;
   //Set the rules logic
       if (rangevalues[i][j] == 1) {
        //Set the cell background
        //test location
        //sheet.getRange(y,x+3).setValue('OK');
        var link = sheet.getRange(y,x+2).getValue();
        var title = sheet.getRange(y,x+1).getValue();
        //title.getText(x+1);
        sheet.getRange(y,x).setBackground("green");
        sheet.getRange(y,x).setFontColor("white");
        showAnchor(title,link);
        range.clear();
      }
   }
  }
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"check stats");
}
```

[see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abyzy.jpg)

P.S. This still has loop holes like if multiple checkboxes were marked (added the range clear function) so I'm still open for suggestions or tweaks.